# Exposing managed C# through C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have this C++/CLI code compiled with /clr.

```
// CppBridge.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.


#include "stdafx.h"
#using <mscorlib.dll>


using namespace System;
using namespace EmulatorLibrary;

using namespace std;

#define EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT const char* exportedCall()
{

    return "exportedCall";
}


public ref class DelegateCLI
{
  private:

  EmulatorDelegate^ emulatorDelegate;

  public:

  DelegateCLI() {

    emulatorDelegate = gcnew EmulatorDelegate();
  }

  String^  callTest() {

    return emulatorDelegate->test();

  }

};
```

Able to call

```
exportedCall()
```

from JNI and Java. I don't have problems with Java at this time.

But now I need to call *callTest()* by exposing it too. The approach is still C++/CLI. Isn't it ? I have seen references to *gcroot* but didn't fully understand the procedure to make this happen.

How do I export *callTest()* in this C++/CLI layer ?

Update 1 : I found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c320cx3h.aspx and I am trying to decipher that.

This isn't supposed to work.

```
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport)
    String^ exportedCall1() {
    EmulatorDelegate^ emulatorDelegate = gcnew EmulatorDelegate();
    return emulatorDelegate->test();

}
}
```

Update 2 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f(v=vs.80).aspx is what I am exploring. But I need to export a function that returns a String returned by a managed function.

This is my best attempt so for. Compiles to DLL. Should work. Right ? Have to test.

```
 class Unmanaged {
 public:
    gcroot<String^> interopstring;
    Unmanaged() {}
 };

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT const char* exportedInteropCall()
{

EmulatorDelegate^ emulatorDelegate = gcnew EmulatorDelegate();
Unmanaged u;
u.interopstring = emulatorDelegate->test();
return (const char*)
(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(u.interopstring)).ToPointer(); // "exportedCall";
}
```

Comment: Yes callTest() is via c++/CLI.    Whether Java can call it directly is another story.   The point of c++/CLI is that it is calllable from managed languages not unmanaged ones

Comment: Not sure why it is voted down after so much research and also some working code. Java does call exportedCall() using JNA successfully.

Comment: Wasn't me.   Here, have a +1.   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code was what I was after. I have executed the .exe in debug mode and tested. I am able to call the C# code from my C++/CLI layer.

```
class Unmanaged {
public:
gcroot<String^> interopstring;
Unmanaged() {}
};

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT const char* exportedInteropCall()
{  
    EmulatorDelegate^ emulatorDelegate = gcnew EmulatorDelegate();
    Unmanaged u;
    u.interopstring = emulatorDelegate->test();
    return (const char*)
    (Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(u.interopstring)).ToPointer(); // "exportedCall";
}
```